# Reshape a 3D matrix to 4D matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, 3d, reshape, 4d

I'm trying to reshape a 3D matrix into 4D. I have a 3D matrix e.g. `X` with dimensions `m`x`n`x`f`. I want a 4D matrix A, with dimensions `m`x`n`x`8`x`k`, where `k=f/8`.

I've tried the following using `mat2cell` but it gives me the error that arguments must be vectors.

```
 A = mat2cell(size(X,1), size(X,2), k*ones(size(X,3)/8));
```

Comment: have you tried `reshape()`?

Comment: No.. Thank you!!